# Меню на Javascript

Tags: javascript

Кто-нибудь скажет, код меню с вложениями. Все на Javascript, вложение одно, то есть наводим на слово Текст 1 и открывается меню а дальше не будет вложений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
ul.menu, ul.menu ul{width:100px}
ul.menu ul{display:none;position:absolute;left:100px;top:-1px}
ul.menu li{position:relative}
ul.menu li:hover > ul{display:block}
</style>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">text1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">text11</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">text111</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">text112</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">text113</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">text12</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">text121</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">text122</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">text123</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">text2</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">text21</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">text22</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">text221</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">text222</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">text223</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">text3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Ничего, что без javascript и с любым уровнем вложенности? Весь "движок" на css.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите -[вот](http://alexwolkov.ru/blognews/WebDesign/jQuery_CSS_Script/podborka_JQuery_i_CSS_menyu_dlya_sayta) тут большая подборка самых разных, а вообще погуглите фразы типа "меню на JQuery" довольно много примеров. Или судя по вопросу (если вроспринимать буквально, то можно и без javascript обойтись)