# Выпадающее меню css без jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

Всем привет.

Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли сделать такое [выпадающее меню](http://sitemaker.x10.bz/articles.php?id=10) с использованием CSS?

Comment: Дякую всім хто витратив свій дорогоцінний час на обговорення моєї проблеми!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно вот так: [jsfiddle.net/shoorick/fSZQC/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/shoorick/fSZQC/1/), чистый CSS3 ;-) Для информации можно сделать и горизонтальный: [jsfiddle.net/shoorick/bp7QM/](http://jsfiddle.net/shoorick/bp7QM/)

```
<div id="ave">
    <h2><a href="#ave">Ave verum</a></h2>
    <p>Ave verum corpus, natum de Maria Virgine, vere passum, immolatum in cruce pro homine,
    cuius latus perforatum unda fluxit et sanguine: esto nobis praegustatum in mortis examine.</p>
</div>

<div id="gaudeamus">
    <h2><a href="#gaudeamus">Gaudeamus</a></h2>
    <p>Gaudeamus igitur, Juvenes dum sumus!
    Post jucundam juventutem, Post molestam senectutem, Nos habebit humus!</p>
</div>

<div id="odi">
    <h2><a href="#odi">Odi et amo</a></h2>
    <p>Quare id faciam, fortasse requiris. Nescio, sed fieri sentio et excrucior.</p>
</div>
```

и

```
body {
    font-family: "Liberation Sans",sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 111%;
}

div {
    background-color: #def;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1s;
    -ms-transition: background-color 1s;
    -o-transition: background-color 1s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
    transition: background-color 1s;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
}

div:target {
    background-color: #ff0;
}

div p {
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #678;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-transition: height 1s, color 1s;
    -ms-transition: height 1s, color 1s;
    -o-transition: height 1s, color 1s;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s, color 1s;
    transition: height 1s, color 1s;

}

div:target p {
    height: 100px;
    color: maroon;
}
```

Comment: Примеры хорошие но явно не под институтский IE :D

Comment: Та да) Обучают студентов в жестких условиях)

Comment: В правильных условиях обучают...

Абсолютному большинству приходится работать именно с тем что и в институте xD

Comment: Абсолютному большинству приходится перерабатывать то чему обучают в институте)

Comment: Дякую) цікава штука!

Comment: Правда весело будет... Скоро IE<7 настолько отдалится от остальных браузеров, что на их фоне будет выглядеть как msdos на фоне windows :DDD

Answer (score 1):

Если с красивостями, то через javascript (css-анимацию сейчас не все браузеры понимают). Если без красивостей, то можно и [на css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/66620/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-javascript?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=66639#66639).

Comment: (ІЕ) - этого можно было и не писать, это и так понятно :D

Скорее всего причина того что не работает - либо **через чур** старый IE, либо **кривой код в примере**

Comment: @AlexWindHope там сам пример кривой) пихать `javascript:ShowOrHide('category2')` при условии что jquery используется - уже на мой взгляд неразумно!

Comment: Чесно кажучи - это **и так понятно**, по теме - никто за вас решать задачи под ваш IE каменного века не будет, разбирайтесь сами, ответ на ваш вопрос очень прост и я вам его дал - **нет нельзя**, считаю вопрос исчерпаным

Comment: дякую і за це:)

Comment: что комменты потерли?

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Css не обрабатывает события по клику

Comment: CSS может только у себя в коде "жабаскрипт" исполнить, я говорю про `expression`

Comment: "CSS может только у себя в коде "жабаскрипт" исполнить" - это что-то новое))

Comment: @Flex [почитай](http://htmlcssjs.ru/JavaScript/?9) тут, и ты поймешь о чем я говорил)) хоть и работает в ослике, но всеже

Answer (score 0):

Разметка:

```
<ul>
    <li>Menu
        <ul>
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
            <li>Option 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Стили:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5em;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    position: relative;
}

ul li:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}

ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    left: 0;
}

ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
    display: list-item;
    position: relative;
}
```